# MongoDB port changes on server restart

Tags: mongodb

I connected to the mongodb via ssh using the mongodb compass, but I found the database port to be 29694 which I don't know where it comes from.

And in node.js, I can only connect to database via ssh in that port.

**Also I found the port is changing when I reboot the server.**

As seen in the screenshot:
[image]

the code I used to connect to the database:

```
var config = {
    username: 'root',
    host:'118.XXX.XXX.X',
    port:22,
    dstHost: '118.XXX.XXX.X',
    dstPort: 27017,
    passphrase: 'XXXX'
};

(async ()=>{
    try {
        await tunnel(config)
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:29694/xxxxx')
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(`${e}`)
    }
    await console.log('connected')
})()
```

I am really just beginning to programming. I don't know where is the problem.

Comment: so what's the problem with that?

Comment: I don't know where that port comes from, and it changes when I reboot the server.

Comment: You should mention the part that the port changes on reboot in the question, the weird port is not a big issue, but the port changing is

Comment: Ah, sorry for that. I added some additional information to the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. Sorry for myself of lacking some basic SSH knowledge.

The correct code is:

```
var config = {
    username: 'root',
    password: 'xxxx',
    host:'118.xxx.xxx.xxx',
    port:22,
    dstHost: '127.0.0.1',
    dstPort: 27017,
    localHost:'127.0.0.1',
    localPort:27000
};

(async ()=>{
    try {
        await tunnel(config)
        await mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27000/xxxx')
    }
    catch(e){
        console.log(`${e}`)
    }
})()
```

And I found [this article](https://blog.trackets.com/2014/05/17/ssh-tunnel-local-and-remote-port-forwarding-explained-with-examples.html) is very helpful for me to understand the ssh port forwarding.